# What is the best way to thumb through photos on the iPad?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibuilder

I and a user to be able to thumb though photos on their iPad, how would I go about doing this via x-code, objective-C or the UI Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your photos side by side on a very large UIView (much larger than the screen).

Make this view a subview of a UIScrollView.  Users can swipe from photo to photo using the scrollview.

For bonus points, put each photo in its own scrollview and all of them in a bigger scrollview to allow swiping and pinching.